# Cinnamon - Change menu entry name on non-English locale

Tags: cinnamon, locale, menu, menu-editor

I'm using Linux Mint 19.3 "Tricia" Cinnamon in French.

The taskbar menu has many programs already existing on fresh install, and I wanted to rename one of then, let's say the driver manager (French name: **Gestionnaire de pilotes**).

On the menu editor, I can find this program: its name is **Gestionnaire de pilotes**, but if I click "Properties", I can see that the name appears as **Driver Manager**, and if I change that name, nothing happens: the French name is still the same.

[image: Here is the menu editor entry : display name is not the real name]

So, where can I find the *French* name of the driver manager in order to modify it?

Comment: _Certainment_, you may pose such questions here, but you may find an answer more quickly by searching in Mint Support https://forums.linuxmint.com/ if you wish. Welcome to StackExchange!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but to be honest I laterally never had any answer when asking on mint forum, I don't know why. I addition to that, I find it harder to search if the question already exists on traditional forum than on stackExchange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desktop launchers are stored in `/usr/share/applications/` or `~/.local/share/applications/`. Find launcher you want edit and open it in text editor. You will see entries named `Name[<lang>]=<name>` and `GenericName[<lang>]=<name>`.

For example in `vlc.desktop`:

```
Name[en_GB]=VLC media player
GenericName[en_GB]=Media player
...
Name[fr]=Lecteur multimédia VLC
GenericName[fr]=Lecteur multimédia
```

Change entries with `fr` and save your file.

Then run `update-desktop-database` as root.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. Whats the difference between `Name` and `GenericName` (I noticed not all launchers have a `GenericName`?

Comment: @sayanel, in some desktop environments you can choose, what to prefer. Then you can see, for example, generic "Media player" instead of the exact name "VLC media player".